# How to get the URL of the Internet explorer tabs with PID of each tab?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have my application which triggers Web Browser with specific URL .
After my program ends i want to close the web pages/tabs which i have opened..

By calling an EXE file with parameters a. Process Name b. String present in the URL

Detailed problem
[How to kill firefox child process/tab from Java/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254379/how-to-kill-firefox-child-process-tab-from-java-c)

I used C# approach ...

I am able to find the process ID of all the tabs..

```
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist) {
    if (theprocess.ProcessName == "iexplore") {
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0}\tID: {1}\tWindow name: {2}",
            theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id, theprocess.MainWindowTitle
        );
    }
}
```

Currently i can get only Window Title of the process....and in IE8 only one window title of main process is visible..

Provided i have the pids of each tabs,How to find the URL of the tab ...and kill only that tab ??

I got this help from 
[Access is denied - when trying to get the url (text) from address bar's handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288092/access-is-denied-when-trying-to-get-the-url-text-from-address-bars-handle/8444478#8444478)

using SHDocVw;
.
.

foreach (InternetExplorer ieInst in new ShellWindowsClass())
   Console.WriteLine(ieInst.LocationURL);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In IE7 and later versions, below code will kill only the tab which has matching string in its URL.

```
   foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
   {
        String url = ieInst.LocationURL;
        if (url.Contains("google"))
        {
            ieInst.Quit();
        }
   }
```

To focus a specific tab the code is :

```
   foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
   {
        String url = ieInst.LocationURL;
        if (url.Contains("google"))
        {
            int val = ieInst.HWND;
            IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(val);
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MAXIMISE);
            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Great info, but why are you talking to yourself? :o/

Comment: Coz evryon viewed it and no body responded :) until i found the solution myself and shared tat as well :P

Comment: Using this code will throw two Errors. One should use "ShellWindows()" instead of "ShellWindowsClass()".

Answer (score 3):

There is a way get the URL of each IExplorer instance  !!

Add a reference "**Microsoft Internet Controls**" to the project.

The piece of code is

```
**foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ieInst.LocationURL);
        }**
```

Generate the exe and Interop.SHDocVw.dll

It will work ...:)