# Can I using java to capture url of active browser window (firefox, ie...)

Tags: java, windows

It's a java desktop, need to capture url of current active browser window. Can I do this with java?

Comment: What is the use-case for this functionality?

Comment: Take a look at the url class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html It allows you to fetch contents from a webpage

Comment: Why vote down :(? I need for a time tracker application, Need to track what my coder doing in their work time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get URL's of all Internet Explorer instances . But through C# approach , i could'nt find a solution using JAVA.

The alternative is to write C# executable which prints the URL , invoke it through java process and get the output.

```
                    String cmd =  "/GetURL.exe ";             
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

You can use the stream readers to determine the output of the command executed .

Explained the C# approach to get the URL of IE objects using SHDOCVW.dll ,

[How to get the URL of the Internet explorer tabs with PID of each tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445742/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-internet-explorer-tabs-with-pid-of-each-tab)

just use C# Express edition 2008 and try the code , it will result in Interop.SHDocVw.dll and an Exe .

Since firefox is a third party application , i dont know if there is any way . 
Internet Explorer comes handy with the OS so it was possible .