# What is the best way to get the internet explorer current url as a string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I am looking for a way to return a url as a string from the current Internet Explorer URL.

This approach uses dde.  It very fast and works well except it returns a very long string in two parts both with quotes.

```
uses
  ddeman;

function GetURL(Service: string): string;
var
  ClDDE: TDDEClientConv;
  temp: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  ClDDE := TDDEClientConv.Create(nil);
  with ClDDE do
  begin
    SetLink(Service, 'WWW_GetWindowInfo');
    temp := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF');
    Result := StrPas(temp);
    StrDispose(temp);
    CloseLink;
  end;
  ClDDE.Free;
end;
```

For example this returns:
"http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/01/counterfeit_android_apps1-100227383-medium.jpg","http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/01/counterfeit_android_apps1-100227383-medium.jpg"

But I am looking for just the first part before the first comma without the quotes:
http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/01/counterfeit_android_apps1-100227383-medium.jpg

Any suggestions for another approach or how to parse the string to produce the result shown without quotes and just the first part of the string?

Comment: Why can't you just extract the part before the comma and then remove the quotes yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445742/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-internet-explorer-tabs-with-pid-of-each-tab

Comment: I wonder how do you define *current* url when there're multiple ie windows with multiple tabs all in background.

Comment: Every time I see a comma-seperated, double-quoted string I got `TStringList.DelimitedText` in my mind :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the string pretty simply yourself:

```
// Extract string up to position of the ,
Temp := Copy(Temp, 1, Pos(',', Temp) - 1);
// Remove double-quotes from resulting string
Temp := StringReplace(temp, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Here's a sample console app that uses the logic above on the sample response you provided, and outputs the final contents to the console:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  LinkStr = '"http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/01/counterfeit_android_apps1-100227383-medium.jpg","http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/01/counterfeit_android_apps1-100227383-medium.jpg"';

var
  Temp: string;

begin
  Temp := Copy(LinkStr, 1, Pos(',', LinkStr) - 1);
  Temp := StringReplace(Temp, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Writeln('After: ' + Temp);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Ken... the quotes are removed ok, but unfortunately the entire string is returned instead of the first part of the string before the comma.

Comment: @Bill: That's not true. See my edited answer, which uses the **exact** string you provided (I copied and pasted it), and outputs just the first portion (up to the comma) with the quotes removed.

Comment: It would be nice to know if there are alternatives to using dde for this as well.  Thanks Ken for your assistance.

Comment: @Bill: You asked for either/or. I didn't have an answer to the first, but the parsing was easy. :-) As you say it's "very fast and works well", and the parsing code is also very fast and works well... ?